# Freeze Excel UDF results OR speed it up (a LOT!)?

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 2010, Windows 7

I have a UDF that is slow. It's currently being used in 4,500 cells which is probably an issue...but then what good would a UDF be if it couldn't be used efficiently more than a few times?  Anyway, sheet calculation takes just under 33 seconds AND the results won't "stick", so if I leave the sheet and then return to it the cells are all blank and it needs to be recalculated again!  Here's the UDF:

```
    Function SumEmployee(EmployeeName As String, ProgramCode As String, Optional bVolatile As Boolean) As Double
'Written tightly to keep execution as fast as possible. Search every sheet for the first instance of the given employee name and the first instance of
'the given program gl-code.  This will give a row-column (the intersection of the row & column) and the value in that cell location
'will be added up for each sheet in the workbook.  The final summed result is returned.
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long, wksSheet As Worksheet

Application.Volatile (bVolatile)  'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx
SumEmployee = 0
For Each wksSheet In Worksheets
    With wksSheet
        If InStr(1, .Name, gTS_Sheet, vbTextCompare) > 0 And bVolatile Then  'Only pull from the TS Summary sheets when HS is visible
            On Error Resume Next  'Errors are part of the routine so this is purposeful
            lRow = .Range("A2:D100").Find(ProgramCode, , xlValues, xlWhole).Row
            lCol = .Range("C2:DA12").Find(EmployeeName, , xlValues, xlWhole).Column
            'If there were no errors then the items were found so sum new value otherwise skip and move to the next sheet
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                SumEmployee = SumEmployee + .Cells(lRow, lCol).Value2  'No errors so get the value in the cell & add to the running total
            Else
                Err.Clear
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0  'Resume normal error handling
        End If
    End With
Next wksSheet
End Function
```

Here is the code for the sheet where the UDF is used:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
'Sheet is active so allow the UDF to function.
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("IsVolatile").RefersToR1C1 = "=TRUE"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
'Leaving sheet so turn off UDF updating so rest of the wkbk won't lag.
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("IsVolatile").RefersToR1C1 = "=FALSE"
End Sub
```

This is how the UDF looks in a cell (note that the first two params change as the UDF is placed in neighboring cells):

```
=SumEmployee(D$5,$A6,IsVolatile)
```

Where the first parameter is the name of the employee to search for and the second parameter is the financial GL code to search for.  The third parameter, IsVolatile, tells the function to run only if the sheet it's in is visible (in the context of my application).

The UDF is in sheet "Master".  The other sheets are a month of data that has employee name across the top (one employee name per column) and GL code down the left (one GL code per row), thus forming a grid.  At the intersection of the row/column is the number of hours the employee worked for that GL code (specific program).  The UDF does a search for the employee and the program because they may vary monthly, that is, a new program may start mid-year so it wouldn't be in the earlier sheets.  Same with employees, they can come and go on a monthly basis, thus the .Find method but methinks this may be what's killing the speed -- which is why I use a specified range of ROUGHLY where to search the rows or columns instead of .Cells for the whole sheet.

1. Is it possible to speed this up?
2. How do I make the results "stick" until the next refresh?

Thank you.

Comment: Some possibilities to speed up: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretse.htm

Comment: I've already been there and I can't see anything to help.  It is a great site though!

Comment: It is quicker to use WorksheetFunction.Match instead of the .Find method but test for lRow = 0 or lCol = 0 inside the On Error Resume Next instead of Err.Number. WorksheetFunction.Match doesn't actually throw an error; Application.Match does but testing for an error first means doing the operation twice which will negate any speed benfit of using Match

Comment: How often do data change? Maybe a function can be made less volatile and the formulae switched to manual calculation mode. One of possibilities could be even a sub, which leaves static values and can be run from a button.

Comment: Jüri - Yes, that's what I've done for now.  It's a non-volatile function and the sheet updates with a form button (embedded on the sheet).  I use the worksheet events to toggle .EnableCalculation.

ooo - I think the WorksheetFunction.Match was taking me into more coding so I abandonded that idea (more code, more processing time to execute UDF). However, testing for Row or Col = 0 makes now makes sense so I may go back and revisit that for a solution.  Thanks for the note about Application vs. Worksheet.